# Dcom Config Excel "This user" works only for one day

Tags: c#, office-interop, dcom

Apologies in advance if my English is not too good.

---

I'm currently developing a web site, in Visual Studio C# using Interop,that is going to let the user download some data into an Excel template. In my machine, there is no problem, but, when I try to run it in the server, there are certain users that have problems, when trying to download the file (The website just continues loading and never download the file or launch a dialog box)

The solution that I found was to change the server Dcom Config for Excel Application Identity to the option of "This user" and it works, for everyone, but, the very next day, I've again the same problem of the website never downloading the file.

If I check again the configuration in my server, I can see that it's the same that I've set the day before in "This user". Then, if I change it again it works.

I've used my credentials and the credentials of the server, but it makes no difference.

---

Is there a way to set the credentials without having to do it daily?

Comment: [What you're doing simply isn't supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2)